# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name is not bound in this Context

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, tomcat, datasource

I try to follow this link: [link](http://jsf-tying-it-all-together.blogspot.com/2012/02/persistence-project-2.html)
I use Tomcat 7. During the deployment from Eclipse I get:

```
    SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'JSFDemoJNDI': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:591)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:469)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:383)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4994)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5492)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate$1.doInContext(JndiTemplate.java:154)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.execute(JndiTemplate.java:87)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:152)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiTemplate.lookup(JndiTemplate.java:178)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiLocatorSupport.lookup(JndiLocatorSupport.java:104)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectLocator.lookup(JndiObjectLocator.java:105)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.lookupWithFallback(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:201)
    at org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(JndiObjectFactoryBean.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 21 more
```

obviously, it cannot find datasource, but I defined it in the server.xml of Tomcat this way:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI"
              global="jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.56.101:1521:main"
              username="jsf"
              password="jsf"
              maxActive="10"
              maxIdle="2"
              minIdle="1"
              maxWait="10000"/>
```

my persistence.xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="JSFDemoPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI</jta-data-source>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class"
                value="org.hibernate.transaction.SunONETransactionManagerLookup" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

    <persistence-unit name="localTestingPU"
        transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>com.sample.entities.PartEntity</class>
        <class>com.sample.entities.OrderPartsEntity</class>
        <class>com.sample.entities.OrderEntity</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="jsf" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.56.101:1521:main" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="jsf" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

And my applicationContext.xml is:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
">   
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.sample"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven/>
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="JSFDemoJNDI" jndi-name="jdbc/JSFDemoJNDI"  resource-ref="true"/>
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="JSFDemoPU"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager" />
    <bean id="persistenceAnnotation" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor" />
   <!--  <import resource="/spring/ServiceAndDaoBeans.xml"/> -->
</beans>
```

Where is the problem?
EDITED:
I think there is a clue somewhere in the message `Unable to find [jdbc]`

EDITED2: I finally found the solution: it seems Eclipse copies server.xml, so I worked with the same copy again and again. Deleting Tomcat from the list of servers and adding it back saved the situation. 
I appreciate all efforts members of SO did here and I am sorry for such a waste of time.

Comment: Which section of server.xml have you defined the resource in? Either this is the problem, or the server.xml you think you have added the definition to isn't the one eclipse is using to run your web application..

Comment: @AnuragKapur  It's inside `<GlobalNamingResources>` tag.

Comment: Did you add the entry to server.xml via eclipse or some other way?

Comment: No, via filesystem. But it worked for other projects.

Comment: Not sure, maybe there is a missing jar file? Would be helpful to see the full stacktrace..

Comment: Added stack trace. not full, but usually the meaningful part.

Comment: Solved, thank you and please see my second Edit.